# Import X509 certificate to certlm with private key (.NET Core 6)

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, .net-6.0

I am generating X509 certificates to authorize apps in Azure using .NET using the below code:

```cs
private static X509Certificate2 BuildSelfSignedCertificate(string CertificateName, int DaysValid)
        {
            SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
            sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.Loopback);
            sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback);
            sanBuilder.AddDnsName("localhost");
            sanBuilder.AddDnsName(Environment.MachineName);

            X500DistinguishedName distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN={CertificateName}");

            using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
            var request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));

            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
               new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                   new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));

            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

            var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(DaysValid)));
#pragma warning disable CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
            certificate.FriendlyName = CertificateName;
#pragma warning restore CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility

            return certificate;
        }
```

This works great, but when I import it the cert using the following, the private key is not included:

```cs
X509Store store = new(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(cert);
            store.Close();
```

However, if I export the cert to a byte array and create a new `X509Certificate2` object from the array, the private key is imported correctly.

```cs
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password"), "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

[image: Cert Image]

Notice the "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate" message.

How can I import the cert + private key without resorting to this awkward workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I import the cert + private key without resorting to this awkward workaround?

By creating the key as a persisted key to begin with.

```
using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
```

This line creates an ephemeral (in-memory only) private key.  Instead you can do

```
CngKeyCreationParameters keyParams = new CngKeyCreationParameters
{
    ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport,
    KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.MachineKey,
    Parameters =
    {
        new CngProperty("Length", BitConverter.GetBytes(2048), CngPropertyOptions.Persist),
    },
};

using CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"), keyParams);
using RSA rsa = new RSACng(cngKey);
```

And now the created certificate is associated with an already-persisted key.

(Note that this snippet uses MachineKey and exportable because that's what the question has as the PFX import flags)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I always like the simple fixes. :)